# MVC 4 Return null even the value does exist in database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I really don't know why it keeps returning null even the value does exist. I need your help
my control

```
 public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        var orders = db.Orders// 1ng co nhieu hoadon
            .Where(h => h.USERID == id).ToList();

        if (orders != null)//each order has detail order, find them and delete
        {
            foreach (Order order in orders)
            {
                var detailorders = db.DetailOrders
                    .Where(detailorder => detailorder.OrderID == order.OrderID).ToList();// Return Null here
                foreach (DetailOrder o in detailorders)
                    db.DetailOrders.Remove(o);

                db.Orders.Remove(order);
            }
        }



        db.Users.Remove(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I don't know why detailorders return null, help me.
my Model:

```
public Order()
    {
        this.DetailOrders = new HashSet<DetailOrder>();
    }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> USERID { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<DetailOrder> DetailOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

and my DetailOrder model. I' using EntiyFramework 5.0.0.0

```
 public partial class DetailOrder
{


    public int OrderID { get; set; } //Primary Key
    public int ProductID { get; set; }// Primary Key


    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product{ get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Whats returning null?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. which method returns null, what is the structure of the table and it's content... did you try to select all without where ?

Comment: @Lucky Lam I couldn't see how are you querying DetailOrder before passing to view. I can see your code for deleting but is that where you facing problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see the problem here, but I will suggest another path in order to skip all this code and instead of looping over orders & details order ,you will need to delete just the order.

unless you can't due to specific design decision, the problem here can be solved by allowing **CascadeDelete** inside your DB.
this way, whenever you delete an order, the DB itself will take care of deleting all the child DetailsOrder for you, and you will skip the headache here.

the way to enable cascadeDelete is shown in the screenshot below:

1. Open the DetailsOrder in the "Design" mode
2. Open "Relationships"
3. Expand the option "INSERT and UPDATE specification"
4. Select "Cascade" for the option "Delete Rule"
5. Hit "Ok" and save your table

[image]
Now whenever you delete an order, all related detailesOrders will be deleted as well, all handled by your DB.

Comment: it works perfectly thank you so much you're a life saver. I really do appreciate your help!